# C++ class: must explicitly initialize the member

Tags: c++, class, variables, constructor, initialization

So, I have made this class called 'Grid'. I also have a class called 'Field'. The Field-class has 4 variables of the type Grid and they are all set in the constructor. except, they're not... Or at least the compiler doesn't think so.

I don't really get why, I set all the variable to a new instance.

When I hover over the red underline (under the constructor) it says: 
"constructor for 'Field' must explicitly initialize the member 'b_attack' which does not have a default constructor"

code:

```
class Grid{
    friend class Field;
private:
    unsigned int xSize;
    unsigned int ySize;
    bool *ptrfield;
    Grid(unsigned int xSize, unsigned int ySize){
        this->xSize = xSize;
        this->ySize = ySize;
        ptrfield = new bool[xSize*ySize];
    }
};

class Field{
private:
    Grid a_own;
    Grid a_attack;
    Grid b_own;
    Grid b_attack;
public:
    Field(unsigned int xSize, unsigned int ySize){
        a_own = Grid(xSize, ySize);
        a_attack = Grid(xSize, ySize);
        b_own = Grid(xSize, ySize);
        b_attack = Grid(xSize, ySize);
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << "aHELLO" << std::flush;
        std::cout << a_own.xSize << std::flush;
    }
};
```

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` for array storage. You're using `new[]` here and you have no corresponding `delete[]`, so this leaks memory, a bad habit to get into. `std::vector` takes care of that for you.

Comment: @tadman yes, I wanted to do that after I made this thing compile... //TODO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your 4 `Grid` member objects are created *before* the body of your `Field` constructor is entered (or at least, the compiler *wants* to generate code to create them - but it can't); see [this cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (bolding mine):

> **Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the
>   constructor begins executing**, initialization of all direct bases,
>   virtual bases, and **non-static data members is finished**. Member
>   initializer list is the place **where non-default initialization of
>   these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be
>   default-initialized**, such as members of reference and const-qualified
>   types, member initializers must be specified. No initialization is
>   performed for anonymous unions or variant members that do not have a
>   member initializer.

From this quote (the remarks about "members that cannot be default-initialized"), we then see that we can provide the required initialization in an initializer list; this is placed immediately after the closing `)` of the constructor declaration, using a `:` followed by the required, comma-separated initializers. Like this, in your case:

```cpp
    Field(unsigned int xSize, unsigned int ySize) : // The ":" starts our initializer list
        a_own(xSize, ySize),      // .. and each one of these constructs a "Grid"
        a_attack(xSize, ySize),
        b_own{ xSize, ySize },    // This "{...}" form is newer and many prefer it,
        b_attack{ xSize, ySize }  // but it can also be a bit confusing
    {
        return; // We now have nothing left to do in the actual "body" of the c'tor!
    }
```

Please feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

*PS: For your posted code, my compiler gives the error you reported for all four `Grid` members; perhaps yours 'gives up' after the first one?*

Comment: For some reason I can't use the 'new form'. It says : {expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers} . But the other one works! Thank you!

Comment: @NikitaDemodov Then it was lucky that I gave examples of both forms! I think the `{...}` form came in with the C++11 standard; if your compiler is using C++98, they won't work, for sure.